# How to change black Google bar back to white?

Tags: google-workspace, google-search

Today, the Google Apps bar went to black. How do you change it back to white?

[image: Google black bar]

Comment: First install GreaseMonkey:  https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ . Second: install GoogleBar Classic GreaseMonkey script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105744 . Say bye to black bar.

Comment: For Chrome just skip GreaseMonkey installation.
Go to http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105744 and click install. Chrome will do the rest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a design change that Google have recently implemented that allegedly focus on three design principles:

> - **Focus:** With the design changes in the coming weeks and months, we’re
>     bringing forward the stuff that
>     matters to you and getting all the
>     other clutter out of your way.
> - **Elasticity:** The new design will soon allow you to seamlessly
>     transition from your desktop computer
>     to your mobile phone to your tablet,
>     while keeping a consistent visual
>     experience. We aim to bring you this
>     flexibility without sacrificing style
>     or usefulness.
> - **Effortlessness:** Our design philosophy is to combine power with
>     simplicity. We want to keep our look
>     simple and clean. But behind the
>     seemingly simple design, the changes
>     use new technologies to make sure you
>     have all the power of the web behind
>     you.

More information can be found on these changes here:

- [Official Google Blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/evolving-google-design-and-experience.html)
- [Inside Search Article](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com/2011/06/some-updates-to-design-of-search.html)
- [Google Help Article](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?&&answer=1364511&hl=en)

<strike>At the moment there isn't any option in your Google account to switch back the styles.  There is [this Userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105723) that will hide the bar for you completely.</strike>

The userscript will more than likely change in the very near future to replace the black styling back to the original white styling:

> **Script Summary:**
>
> Hides the annoying Black Bar from Google Search
>   pages. More updates coming soon to
>   replace the current styles with older
>   one
>   Further details on the [Script homepage](http://techie-buzz.com/annoyances/remove-google-search-black-bar.html)

**UPDATE**

The script has now been updated to remove the black styling and revert back to the old white and blue style.

This script can be found [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105744)

Comment: What about "The Client Is Always Right" principle?

Comment: Ha! This is Google - *they* are always right! ;)

Comment: @Coola: The problem is that there is more than one client now and making everything customizable makes it inconsistent and hard to manage.