# Gmail/Google search: change color of top bar back to white from new black

Tags: google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change black Google bar back to white?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16664/how-to-change-black-google-bar-back-to-white)

Some time ago, Google changed the color of the top bar ("Web Images Videos Maps News Shopping Gmail more") to black. How can I change the color back to white?

PS: my browsers are Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

Comment: Google retired the "black bar" a long time ago. This should just be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You could use greasemonkey ( [extention needed for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) , [chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/02/40000-more-extensions.html) and [opera](http://my.opera.com/Contrid/blog/2007/02/11/how-to-greasemonkey-in-opera) support greasemonkey natively)  with [a user script that does it](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105735)

Answer (score 1):

[Stylish](http://userstyles.org/) is an addin that allows you to apply custom CSS styles.